# Quantitative difference of two datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value, dataset

I have two biological datasets with different samples (rows) and same features (columns). I mean that I have D1 (M1 x N) size and D2 (M2 x N) size. M1, M2 is order of 2000, N is order of 500. All value are continous (float)

I need to build some quantitative estimation on how much this datasets are different relatively their features. In other words, how much distribution of all features are different between two datasets.

I can do independent analysis by each feature ( it would like U-test of comparison of distribution for each feature). But I am interesting in getting some integral estimation on whole dataset ( in features alltogether ). Could you suggest some method?

It would be perfect if result will also be in p-value units.

Comment: Please be more specific about what kinds of differences in the features you wish to test.  Although there are techniques for detecting literally *any* difference between two multivariate datasets, it is rare for them to be appropriate.  Usually people are looking for definite kinds of differences, such as differences in central tendency, differences in correlation, etc.

Comment: differences of mean distribution for exampe. 2nd example is mean + std. 3rd example is equality of distribution itself ( u-test ). But I need some estimaton for features alltogether